# Determine whether table or view on linked server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server

I have views in a database that are populated by connecting to (and selecting from) a linked server. Unfortunately I cannot see the objects associated with the linked server due to my permission level.

I am trying to determine if the object I am connecting to on the linked server is a table or a view.

I scripted the view out into a CREATE to statement

```
SELECT * FROM [linked_server].[database].[schema].[abcd]
```

So any way for me to tell if abcd is a table or a view?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below script provides the information, there are additional stored procedures as well for more details.

```
exec sp_tables_ex [linked_server]
```